# main() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code

```
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'dataset'  # replace with your dataset ID
table_id = 'table'  # replace with your table ID
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request
rows_to_insert = []
bq = bigquery.Client(project='project-id')
query = """SELECT Url FROM `project-id.dataset.urltable`"""
query_job = bq.query(query)
data = query_job.result()
rows = list(data)


def main():
    for row in rows:
        URL = urllib.request.urlopen(row[0])
        soup_page = soup(URL, features="lxml")
        try:
            data = json.loads(soup_page.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[1].text)
        except:
            data ='unknown'
        try:
            price_ruw = data['offers']['price']
            shopprice = price_ruw.replace(',','.')
        except: 
            price = 0
        try:
            ean = data['gtin13']
            ean = str(ean)
        except:
            ean = 'unknown'
        try:
            title_ruw1 = data['name']
            title_ruw = title_ruw1
            tile_trim = title_ruw[:750]
            title = tile_trim.replace("'", "")
        except:
            title = "unknown"            
        try:
            reviews = data['aggregateRating']['reviewCount']
        except:
            reviews = 0
        try:
            score =  (float(data['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']) * 2)
        except:
            score = 0
        datenow = (datetime.datetime.now())
        shoplink = row[0]
        rows_to_insert.append([shoplink,ean,title,reviews,score,shopprice,datenow])
    client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request
main()
```

Testing this code in Google Cloud platform gives

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
main() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

However when deploying this code it does not give an error. Only scheduling this query does not work since it keeps giving the error below.

[image]

For deploying i use the following command (which works)

```
gcloud functions deploy <function> --entry-point main --
runtime python37 --trigger-resource <name> --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish --timeout 540s
```

Comment: Where is your `rows` defined. Is this the full code?

Comment: @Frank can you paste full stack trace?

Comment: Aside rows and client are not defined, everything else works smoothly when I try to call it. Check if you dont have two calls of a function, or if you didnt overwrite function with some other.

Comment: Are you running this code in Cloud Functions? If yes, you need to use an entrypoint function and not `main()`. Also post all your code including the imports. Show how you are running this program (command line). Context is important when debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply's. I added more context. 
- Changing main() to function() does not work. When deploying it gives an error : file main.py is expected to contain a function called main. I removed --entry-point main

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear how you're trigging this function, but it seems like a "Background Function", which means that it needs to take two arguments, even if they're unused:

```
def main(data, context):
   ...
```

See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers for more information.

Comment: When deploying with main(data,context) i get the following error: 

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: main() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'data' and 'cont
ext'

Comment: This is because you're calling `main()` at the bottom of your file, you don't need to do this.